# Why does a variable holding the result of Vec::get_mut not need to be mutable?

Tags: rust, mutability

I have the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(String::from("Foo"));
    let mut row = vec.get_mut(0).unwrap();
    row.push('!');
    println!("{}", vec[0])
}
```

It prints out "Foo!", but the compiler tells me:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     let mut row = vec.get_mut(0).unwrap();
  |         ----^^^
  |         |
  |         help: remove this `mut`
```

Surprisingly, removing the `mut` works. This raises a few questions:

- Why does this work?
- Why *doesn't* this work when I use `vec.get` instead of `vec.get_mut`, regardless of whether I use `let` or `let mut`?
- Why doesn't `vec` work in the same way, i.e. when I use `let vec = Vec::new()`, why can't I call `vec.push()`?

Comment: Looks like it's essentially being borrowed for a bit before returning to `vec`. [Similar example.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5146d3407d26f179967532fb5b525988)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec.get_mut(0)` returns an `Option<&mut String>`, so when you `unwrap` that value you will have a mutable borrow of a `String`.  Remember, that a `let` statement's left side is using pattern matching, so when your *pattern* is just a variable name you essentially say match whatever is on the right and call it *name*.  Thus `row` matches against `&mut String` so it already is mutable.

Here's a much simpler and more straightforward example to illustrate the case (which you can try in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e297733c54b56a681cadb969125d54d)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 55i32;
    dbg!(&x);
    let y = &mut x; // <-- y's type is `&mut i32`
    *y = 12;
    dbg!(&x);
}
```